# Visual Studio C++ compiler flag: what is -Zm200?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compiler-flags

I use Qt for C++ development, and today I produced a .vcproj file from a .pro file.

I noticed under the vcproj project properties, Qt added this flag into the C/C++ -> Command Line -> Additional Options

```
-Zm200
```

What is -Zm200?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

-Zm is Specify Precompiled Header Memory Limit (more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdscwf1c.aspx)).  It limits the amount of memory the compiler can allocate for processing precompiled headers.  For Visual C++ 2008, -Zm200 means limit to 150 MB.

Comment: this is quite strange. if you look at the article pointed out by Eric, that article says 210MB!

Comment: Eric's article refers to VC++ 6.0.  My link points to VC++ 2008.  2005 has a different number, 2010 will probably be different still.

Comment: Hey its msdn no one expect them to be either accurate or useful ^^

Comment: According to the documentation for VC6 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278580%28VS.60%29.aspx) the number is a scaling factor.  It also mentions that the default limit is about 105MB.  So 200 means 200% (hence 2x105 = 210).  The default in VS2008 must be 75 MB if Michael is correct above.

Answer (score 3):

This limits the maximum heap size *for the compiler* [according to this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278580(VS.60).aspx). So this doesn't affect your program at all